# Opening a file externally using C program

Tags: c, gedit

I'd like to create a program that causes a running `gedit` process to open a `.txt` file in a new tab using C. The file would be the argument I supply to the program. However, I'd like to avoid using `system()` altogether.

I'm on Linux. Is this possible? If so, by what means?

Comment: You want to write a program that when run opens another tab in gedit containing the text file you passed as an argument to the program?

Comment: explain a little bit more.... you are going to write a program that opens the file in a tab in gedit?

Comment: I'm guessing he is looking for some kind of `system()` call...

Comment: @TimPost Yes, Exactly!. But without any system() functions.

Comment: @Gomathi I've made some edits for clarity to your question, please check to make sure they're accurate.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the system call because you don't want your program to block?

Comment: What's the problem with `system()`? How about [`exec`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec)?

Comment: @TimPost They are accurate. THanks.

Comment: @XiaoJia There's no big reason, actually. But I'd like to implement it programmatically.

Comment: Gedit might expose itself over DBus and if so you could use that. But this relies on Gedit being available (and running) and when all is said and done system() with xdg-open is probably easier by far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `system()`. You can use fork/execlp

```
if(!fork())
    execlp("gedit", "gedit", filename, NULL);
```

The version of gedit that's on my laptop uses a new tab by default if there's a running instance already, but I'm not sure about other versions.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is to not hardcode the editor's executable name into your application. Users might not have gedit installed at all (it's mostly only there if the system runs Gnome.) What you do instead is use `xdg-open` with the file you want to open as its argument. For example:

```
system("xdg-open myfile.txt");
```

If the user is instead using gedit as the default editor, this will open the file in a new tab if gedit is already running. If it's not running, it will be started first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

Step 1. Modify `gedit` source file (function: `is_in_viewport()` to return `TRUE`)
    (see [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75671/why-does-gedit-keep-randomly-opening-new-instances-when-opening-files-from-nauti)).

Step 2. Use `fork()`/`execl()` in program and call this modified gedit (there are a few examples
    [here](http://www.gidforums.com/t-3369.html)).

Comment: It seems a terribly bad idea to carry around a hacked up and inevitably outdated version of gedit just so your application can pop up this almost-but-not-quite-gedit. Plus, package management.

Comment: @user268396, gEdit algorithmic viewpoint computation to open file in new window or existing one *must* be answered in order to address this requirement(unless you want to change the requirements here), so was my solution. You are free to present your solution.

Comment: "I'd like to avoid `system()`" is not usually how one would phrase a must-have requirement. So it can be bent, especially if it leads to _better_  solutions (or sticking to the wish yields worse results, whichever view you prefer to take). As for the rest: I have no idea what you're on about; there again, English is not my native tongue so I might simply be missing the obvious.